# stop following a user if it does not follow any post from this user

Tags: ruby, methods, if-statement, ruby-1.9

**I want to stop following a user if and only if I have left to follow all his posts.**

For this I have tried with this method but does not works for me.

```
user_with_posts = User.find(params[:id])
posts_of_users = user_with_posts.posts
posts_of_users.each do |post|
current_user.unfollow(user_with_posts) unless current_user.follows?(post)
end
```

The problem here is that if user_with_post have 3 posts and current_user only follow 1 post the code run the **current_user.unfollow(user_with_posts)**

**I want only run the **current_user.unfollow(user_with_posts)** if and only if I have left to follow all the post for **user_with_posts**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) for this purpose:

> *any? [{|obj| block } ]* → true or false
>
> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method
>   returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or
>   nil. If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of {|obj|
>   obj} (that is any? will return true if at least one of the collection
>   members is not false or nil.

```
user_with_posts = User.find(params[:id])
posts_of_users = user_with_posts.posts
current_user.unfollow(user_with_posts) unless posts_of_users.any? do |post|
  current_user.follows?(post)
end
```